# sccm 2012 r2 some reports return error

Tags: sccm, reporting

I recently upgraded from SCCM 2012 SP1 to SCCM 2012 R2. There are some issues with some reports not working (also SMS_PORTALWEB_CONTROL_MANAGER returns errors, but that may not be related). I had some WMI corruption issues on the server, had to run a restore from wmimgmt.msc and have not had WMI errors in the eventlog since. However the reporting issues persist.

Will insert error message here as i cannot attach a file.

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'S-1-5-21-304347872-1734857272-171853879-7318' to data type int.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005Impl.GetReportParameters(String Report, String HistoryID, Boolean ForRendering, ParameterValue[] Values, DataSourceCredentials[] Credentials, ReportParameter[]& Parameters)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005.GetReportParameters(String Report, String HistoryID, Boolean ForRendering, ParameterValue[] Values, DataSourceCredentials[] Credentials, ReportParameter[]& Parameters)

-------------------------------
Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.SmsException
An error has occurred during report processing.


Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ParameterPresenter.GetParameters()
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ParameterPresenter.LoadParameters(IReport report, Collection`1 navigationParameters, IResultObject resultObject)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ReportViewerPresenter.Worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)

-------------------------------

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'S-1-5-21-304347872-1734857272-171853879-7318' to data type int.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005Impl.GetReportParameters(String Report, String HistoryID, Boolean ForRendering, ParameterValue[] Values, DataSourceCredentials[] Credentials, ReportParameter[]& Parameters)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005.GetReportParameters(String Report, String HistoryID, Boolean ForRendering, ParameterValue[] Values, DataSourceCredentials[] Credentials, ReportParameter[]& Parameters)


Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ParameterPresenter.GetParameters()
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ParameterPresenter.LoadParameters(IReport report, Collection`1 navigationParameters, IResultObject resultObject)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ReportViewerPresenter.Worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)

-------------------------------





Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportServerException
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)


Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReportSoapProxy.OnSoapException(SoapException e)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute[TReturn](RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod`1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod`1 retryMethod)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.LoadReport(String Report, String HistoryID)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ReportViewerWindowsForms.SetParameterValues_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)

-------------------------------

Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportServerException
Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)


Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReportSoapProxy.OnSoapException(SoapException e)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute[TReturn](RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod`1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod`1 retryMethod)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.LoadReport(String Report, String HistoryID)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ReportViewerWindowsForms.SetParameterValues_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)

-------------------------------

Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportServerException
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'S-1-5-21-304347872-1734857272-171853879-7318' to data type int.


Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReportSoapProxy.OnSoapException(SoapException e)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute[TReturn](RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod`1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod`1 retryMethod)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.LoadReport(String Report, String HistoryID)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ReportViewerWindowsForms.SetParameterValues_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)

-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue is to reinstall the reporting services role in SCCM.

Go to administration > site configuration > servers and site system roles > mark site server > right click reporting services point > remove. Wait 15 mins, right click site server > add site system roles > follow on screen wizard to select reporting services point role.

Comment: -1, Are you saying this was the answer to your problem? Please elaborate.

Comment: By marking this as an answer i am indeed saying this was the answer, yes...

Comment: This post is indeed the answer as i have later had that confirmed by Microsoft Premier Support.

Answer (score 0):

Re-register the WMI class using a command similar to this (the path will vary depending on your version of SQL)

```
C:\Windows\system32>mofcomp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Sha
red\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"
```

SOURCE [technet forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ae08aa43-054d-47e7-99fb-c4f101962478/reports-not-working-after-upgrade-to-sccm-2012-r2-?forum=configmanagergeneral)